# A personal name ending in -ua: is it male or female?

Tags: names

We have the name of a Romano-British Potter from the 2nd century A.D. whose name is SECVNDVA. Is this a male or a female name?

Answer (score 7):

This may really be SECVNDVS: when computers try to automatically transcribe older letters, S is often mistakenly transcribed as A. And SECVNDVS (= Secundus) is a common male name.

I have never heard of SECVNDVA (-VA doesn't look right to me).

SECVNDA, however, would be a common female name. The ending -A is feminine for this type of word.

We could be more certain if you could provide us with more context. A photo, a scan, more information about the source.

Comment: I also think it's most likely to be Secundus. cf. SECVΛDVS.FE https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/H_1853-0502-220 (a side note: do we even know of any female potters in Roman Britain?)

Comment: @AlexB.: Good example. I wouldn't expect female potters in Britain either.

Comment: the only source I can find that mentions Secundua [sic] is Buckland, P.C., Hartley, K.F. and Rigby, V. 2001. The Roman Pottery Kilns at Rossington Bridge. Excavations 1956–1961. Journal of Roman Pottery Studies Volume 9. Oxford: Oxbow/Study Group for Roman Pottery. We'll need to see a photo to speculate further.

Comment: While computers may have difficulties transcribing the letter S and mistake it as A, please note that also on standard English keyboard, the S key is next to the A key and people may have a similar difficulty too. Then if the name is foreign, a proofreader may miss that easily.

Comment: Update: a quote from NAA Monograph Series No. 3 Artefacts Volume 2 A Roman Roadside Settlement at Healam Bridge: The Iron Age to Early Medieval Evidence :110  : “ The optimum date of Sarrius’s productions in north-east England and in Scotland is within the period AD 140-165. They were not necessarily contemporary, but the wall-sided mortaria made at Bearsden and at Rossington Bridge (**stamped by his associate Secundua**) would best
fit a date no earlier than c.AD 140. Further details of his work can be found in Buckland et al. (2001, 45-47) and Breeze (2016)” [emphasis mine - Alex B.]

Comment: A quote from Breeze 2016: 143 : “ The multi-potter workshop at Rossington Bridge, near Doncaster
At some point in the Antonine period Sarrius became involved in a pottery workshop at Rossington Bridge where his stamp sometimes appears alongside a stamp of either Setibogius or Secundua (Buckland et al 2001). It has always been supposed that they were local potters who were acting as ‘agents’ for Sarrius, but it would make more sense if they were the two potters sent by him from his headquarters workshop in Warwickshire and if they were allowed to put their names on the vessels as well as his.”

Answer (score 3):

While "Secundus" was a common male name, "Secunda"  (not "Secundua") would be a common female "name".  For most of Roman history, women did not have given names, only family names, so they were distinguished by birth order (or presumably by nicknames in less formal settinds).  "Secunda" would have been the second-oldest daughter.

Males were not as often named by ordinal numbers, but could be.  In the case of a male, that would be his official given name (*praenomen*).  Also, for men, these need not indicate birth order. You might be called "Quintus" after your grandfather "Quintus", for example

Comment: The question says *Secundua*, though.

Comment: I'm not aware of that as a word, much less a name, which would be why I misread it.

Comment: @Cerberus I misread it myself! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the others that *Secundua* is an unlikely name.
It is probably a misspelling for *Secundus* or *Secunda*.
Let me, however, entertain the possibility that the name is actually *Secundua* and see which gender it should be.

The name *Secundua* would have to be in the Latin first declension.
(There are also three Greek types of first declension words, but this would be in the only Latin type.)
Most words and names in this group are feminine, like *Secunda* would be.
But not all are; there are exceptions both in names (*Seneca*) and other words (*nauta*).
Whether cognomina (e.g. Seneca and Pansa) are masculine or natural gender is a matter of taste, but they are at least mostly used as masculines — the only conclusion I want from these is that you cannot reliably deduce the gender from the ending of the name.

Based on form alone you could thus reasonably guess that it is feminine but you couldn't be sure.
You simply cannot deduce the gender by looking at the name; you actually have to know the name to be sure.

Comment: Strictly.speaking, don't all *cognomina* have natural gender?  *Seneca* is whatever gender its referent is.  (I'm not sure the extent to which women used *cognomina*, but since *cognomina* were sometimes treated as heritable, this must have happened at least once in a while.)

Comment: @CMonsour Cognomina were mostly used by males, at least as an only name. Typically the name *Seneca* is used to refer to Lucius Annaeus Seneca, a male (or two). Modern last names have arguably natural gender, but Roman cognomina aren't quite the same. And the main point is: cognomina like Seneca and Pansa can refer to males despite looking feminine, so you can't deduce the gender from form alone.

Comment: So would one of their daughters, for disambiguation, have been *Annaea Seneca*, *Annaea Senecae*, or *Annaea Senecarum*?

Comment: @CMonsour Good question! I recommend taking that to a separate question. My only point here was that Seneca is most often masculine; whether it is always masculine is irrelevant for my argument but certainly interesting. It would be a digression here, though.

Answer (score 2):

some images from Buckland et al. (2001) - there should be more but I don't have access to it yet.

[image]

[image]